# Selecting IC For Heater Power Control Circuit

Tags: pcb, fpga, motor-controller, driver

I want to manually control a heater (DC Load) through a "power circuit" enabling one of MCU or FPGA IO. For my power circuit my intention to use an IC (switching regulator maybe) as safety and linearity. My input is 24-32V. Heater is DC; it's max voltage is 28V and 190W (+-%10).

[image: heater control circuit]

So problem is which IC should use and how must be connections (resistors, capacitors etc together with it)? Can you help me for this circuit? Thanks.

Comment: What is the IO votlage out of the FPGA? How often will the control state switch? What have you tried so far? What's wrong with getting the FPGA to drive a FET and using that to switch a power relay?

Comment: Its hard to design anything without knowing any details of your heater. What type of input does it take? Does it have any IC or something else which supplies current to the heating element? Can you post a schematic of its interface?

Comment: @Amit M it's a DC heater as i noted, maks working voltage is 28v @ 190W +-10, there is no IC in it.

Comment: It would seem that you just have a  heater which is the load and it must be interfaced somehow with a FPGA with a power circuitry in between.  There would be some power supplying ICs like MOSFET gate drivers or IGBTs which can probably supply current at that power. You have to somehow connect these driver ICs to the FPGA and to a voltage source which can deliver that current. The ICs are controlled with PWM. There may be simple solutions.

Comment: It's no different from controlling a heater using a microcontroller - use a transistor switch circuit to control the heater, and the microcontroller/FPGA can control the transistor. If it's a really big heater you might use the transistor to control a bigger transistor or an even bigger relay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are OK with setting the FPGA to do standard CMOS 3V3 output, it would be possible to attach that to a logic level FET and use that to switch power to heater.

28V at 210W (using the max tolerance) gives 7.5A. So a 10A, 30V FET would in theory do the job. But I’d find the fuse used on the heating element and make sure the FET can handle that current (that way if it goes wrong the fuse blows, but the FET doesn’t). I’d probably also get a 40V or 60V FET to ensure the FET has a long life.

The schematic could be as simple as I've shown below (more so if you are able to set the FPGA to a good enough internal pull downs, and can get away without the series reistor depending on your FET and FPGA combo). But could be made more complicated depending on what other restrictions/requriements you have.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMkb35.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Like most FPGA io it has 3.3v output. There is nothing wrong Fet or Switch Regulator ( for different project i saw fpga control 7.5v buck converter using io), Fet or Regulator just want to learn working circuit. Heater will open or close manually commanded by other computer.

Comment: FPGAs can have lots of different output options, LVDS (various types), 3V3, 1V8, 2V5 [Edited by a moderator to remove obsolete part, after comment was moved.]

Comment: fpga side is clear as you mentioned thanks for schematic it's great and FPGA side is ok but my question is power side :    28v input ------- IC ---------- Heater.

Comment: I don't understant your question. Ask a new question if you have something new to ask

Comment: This could work with the FET acting as a low side driver.

Comment: @Puffafish Updated question and added a pilot to be clarify my question.

Comment: @Amit M can we use IC ınstead to be more safe.

Comment: What would make an IC “more safe”?

Comment: Typically, you use a low side or high side driver which are IC's. Or, you can also use IGBT. I havent checked which of the above  ICs match your power requirements. You can search for such IC's on semiconductor manufacturers websites.

Comment: @Amit M i found lm5116 what do you think about that, can use it ?

Comment: @Puffafish heater is load so it has 2 leg, in your circuit it is like serial to circuit can you pls make ıt paralel like we were sending current and turning back.

Comment: First: lm5116 is a DC converter. What were you planning to use it for? As for the heater, yes it's two legs, one goes to the 28V rail, one routed to 0V through a FET. If I change my schematic, it would be wrong. I don't think you understand what you're trying to achive. I think you need to do some reading to understand what you're trying to do and then ask one question at a time.

Comment: Ramos lm5116 seems a voltage regulator.

Comment: @Puffafish My plan was to control lm5116 to switch heater power on/off. 28V ınput to 28v or around 26V output 8A sinkıng source usıng IC. In your circuit i couldnt understand whıch legs will go to aırbone connector heater ınterfaces ( 2 pıns). Pls evaluate and compare your solutıon with lm5116 one. Accepted your answer thanks for effort.

Comment: @Amit M yes, my ınput ıs 28V so i dont need to boost or buck just need to switchıng power, whats your opınıon whıch one ıs true, and what do you thınk about Puffafish purposed circuıt. Thanks.

Comment: Puffafish's circuit seems close to your requirement. Usually for gate drivers, input is at 3.3V or 5V so those resistors may not be necessary. I havent seen the FET used though.

Comment: @Ramos you can see in the diagram the heater has 2 legs. One on the top and one on the bottom

Comment: You’re not answering my question.